# In Wordpress, on every page, sometimes multiple times, there's a piece of PHP code showing up

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not familiar with Wordpress, but have to fix this for a friend.

On every page there's PHP code showing up.
In control panel, and also just as a regular visitor.
Even when there's a simple pop-up.

Somebody has an idea from where this code is coming?

[image]

Comment: Try disabling the plugins one at a time and see if that's the cause, I would also suggest updating WordPress.

Comment: Its coming because of bad coding.Check your theme's function.php file. According to given screenshot i am guessing its coming from these file.

Comment: It was a plugin "wp-pngfix/pngfix.php". Thanks for the solution!

Comment: plese accept an answer or write and accept your own answer. but (solved) in title is not used here.

Comment: The first comment, as remarked in my comment above here, is the answer. But I can't select a comment as answer. 

Please show me how and I'll always do it right in the future.

Comment: Just add your own answer @Shane, and then click the tick. The button is called "Post your own answer" or similar.

Comment: I've added my answer, but can only accept it in 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

This looks potentially like a failed injection or bad code. I wouldnt touch anything (don't wanna mess up timestamps), and contact your hosting providers security team if you have that option.

What leads me to believe this is that its occurrence is all over the place, and specifically the user's control panel. Do you see that failure to evaluate that code on the blogs home page?

You can use this command at the root of the blog to locate recently modified `.php` files within a week:

```
find -type f -name '*.php' -mtime -7 -ls
```

See anything like `base64_decode` that looks odd in the list of files returned

Answer (score 0):

It was a plugin "wp-pngfix/pngfix.php" that generated the bad code. After disabling it, everything is fine.
Thanks for the solution @MrHunter!